# Removing text between two strings over multiple lines

Tags: bash, sed, lines

I have a log file that generates timestamp and command logging on separate lines. I'd like to strip out the timestamp and save just the "user: command" list. I've tried several permutations of sed to replace or delete the data between strings, but it always oversteps the bounds of the command. Current log output similar to:

```
USER 001
6:32am
USER 001
random bash command or output 001
USER 002
7:41am
USER 002
random bash command or output 002
USER 001
7:43am
USER 001
random bash command or output 003
USER 002
7:43am
USER 002
random bash command or output 004
```

Desired output:

```
USER 001
random bash command or output 001
USER 002
random bash command or output 002
USER 001
random bash command or output 003
USER 002
random bash command or output 004
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this will do:

```
sed -ri 'N; /^.*\n[0-9]/d'
```

(Assumes GNU sed.)

It processes the file two lines at a time.
On each cycle:

- sed automatically reads one line into the pattern space.
- The N command appends to the pattern space a newline and the next line.
- If the pattern space matches "any text, newline, digit", then delete
  it (and therefore don't auto-print it).
- Otherwise, auto-print it.

Answer (score 1):

If file is in same format all time, you can just remove the line like this:

```
awk 'NR%4!=1 && NR%4!=2' file
USER 001
random bash command or output 001
USER 002
random bash command or output 002
USER 001
random bash command or output 003
USER 002
random bash command or output 004
```

Or you can use it like this:

```
awk '!(NR%4==1 || NR%4==2)' file
```